# After germination, how warm do chilli plants need to be?

Tags: chili, temperature

How does temperature affect the growth of the chill plant after germination?

I am currently working on the understanding that to germinate, chilli seeds need to be kept at 25°C during the day for 12 hours, and at least 10°C at night.

For instance, will the chilli plant grow better after germination if the same rule is applied (25°C at day, 10°C at night) throughout the plant’s entire life?

Answer (score 1):

I m from india and outside temperature now is about 40 C. However the heat never hampered the growth. I put the pot in a place where it go direct sun for a few hrs and rest of the day it was in indirect sunlight. The plant is flourishing.

Also in india chilli crops are grown and sunlight or heat never seems a problem

Comment: Thanks for the info, it’s useful to know that heat cannot hamper growth. I still wonder how lack of heat can affect growth.

Comment: I tried germination in shade and it did not work. I then kept it in a place e that got good sunlight. It worked. So I guess plenty of sunlight while keeping the soil.moist is the answer. Can share a pic of my current germination  if this site allows else mail me.at kapilkaushik@outlook.com